# SELECT FROM Table WHERE exact number not partial is in a string SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like, contains

I have a table that contains a bunch of numbers seperated by a comma.

I would like to retrieve rows from table where an exact number not a partial number is within the string.

EXAMPLE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `uids` text NOT NULL,
  `islive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `teams` (`id`, `name`, `uids`, `islive`) VALUES
(1, 'Test Team', '1,2,8', 1),
(3, 'Test Team 2', '14,18,19', 1),
(4, 'Another Team', '1,8,20,23', 1);
```

I would like to search where 1 is within the string.

At present if I use Contains or LIKE it brings back all rows with 1, but 18, 19 etc is not 1 but does have 1 within it.

[I have setup a sqlfiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e6ccd/5)

Do I need to do a regex?

Comment: And this is why you don't store data like that in a SQL table.

Comment: Is it too late to take this table structure behind the barn and shoot it, because this is what you should do... Start over and structure this data properly and it will save you loads of time and suffering down the road.

Comment: Probably the best way to do this is to use a string split function and compare against the results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need 1 condition:

```
select *
from teams
where concat(',', uids, ',') like '%,1,%'
```

Comment: @TheImpaler -- sure it does he is adding in the commas to the start and end.

Comment: Just hope that there are no spaces between the commas.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably catch them all with a OR

```
SELECT ...

WHERE uids LIKE '1,%'
OR  uids LIKE '%,1'
OR uids LIKE '%, 1'
OR uids LIKE '%,1,%'
OR uids = '1'
```

Comment: @Hogan I never say definitely when it comes to people storing data that is not normalized.

Answer (score 3):

I would search for all four possible locations of the ID you are searching for:

- As the only element of the list.
- As the first element of the list.
- As the last element of the list.
- As an inner element of the list.

The query would look like:

```
select *
from teams
where uids = '1' -- only
   or uids like '1,%' -- first
   or uids like '%,1' -- last
   or uids like '%,1,%' -- inner
```

Comment: `uids = '1' -- only`

Comment: Changed it. Even though `LIKE` works, `=` is more intuitive.

Comment: Yeah, it might be marginally faster if it does not need to use pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which version of SQL Server you're using, but if you're using 2016+ you have access to the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function which you can use in this case. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #T
     (
        id int,
        string varchar(20)
     )

     INSERT INTO #T
     SELECT 1, '1,2,8' UNION
     SELECT 2, '14,18,19' UNION
     SELECT 3, '1,8,20,23' 


     SELECT * FROM #T
     CROSS APPLY string_split(string, ',')
     WHERE value = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You SQL Fiddle is using MySQL and your syntax is consistent with MySQL.  There is a built-in function to use:

```
select t.*
from teams t
where find_in_set(1, uids) > 0;
```

Having said that, FIX YOUR DATA MODEL SO YOU ARE NOT STORING LISTS IN A SINGLE COLUMN.  Sorry that came out so loudly, it is just an important principle of database design.

You should have a table called `teamUsers` with one row per team and per user on that team.  There are numerous reasons why your method of storing the data is bad:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Columns should contain a single value.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- SQL (in general) has lousy string handling functions.
- The resulting queries cannot be optimized.
- Simple things like listing the `uid`s in order or removing duplicate are unnecessarily hard.